# How can I replace a nested <resourcecount> within a <condition> with ant 1.6?

Tags: ant

I'm working with Ant 1.6 and [cannot use a "resourcecount" within a "condition"](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html). Basically, I'd like to check if a FileSet contains elements according to regex:

```
<condition property="foo.exist">
   <resourcecount when="greater" count="0">
     <filelist dir="." files="*foo*" />
   </resourcecount>
</condition>
```

Normally this would assign the property foo.exist if the current directory contains the pattern "foo" inside the names.
But I cannot do that within ant 1.6.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit your question, the editor assumes you're trying to insert html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<path id="a">
    <fileset dir=".">
         <include name="*foo*"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<property name="foo.exist" refid="a"/>

<echo>${foo.exist}</echo>
```